# Find the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}x^{3n}$.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence for the following summation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}x^{3n}$$

I don't know how to deal with the $(2n)!$ in this question. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the x^3n in your title means $x^{3n}$.

**Hint**.  Use the ratio test:
$$\left|\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!}x^{3n+3}\bigg/\frac{(2n)!}{n!}x^{3n}\right|
  =\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(n+1)n!}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}|x|^3$$
and now lots of things cancel.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain how the (2n+2)! turns into (2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)! ?

Comment: $(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)\cdots1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\dfrac{(x+1)!}{x!}=\dfrac{(x+1)\cdot x!}{x!}=x+1$$